# Получения элемента с таблицы (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем у меня есть примерно такой код:

```
 <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>This is</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" class="btn btn-primary">Один </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" class="btn btn-primary">Два</button>
               </td>
           </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

Нажимаю я к примеру на кнопку "Один", и мне нужно получить текст вверхнего td (This is), то есть чтоб гибко было, получало рядом td, исключительно через jquery надо. Пробовал наподобии такого (с другой таблицей), не получалось.

```
 $("#create").find("#aga").parent("#s").text();
```

Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```
$('.btn-info').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('td').prev().text())
})
```

тут суть в том, что вы возвращаетесь до ближайшего td ($(this).closest('td')) и берёте предыдущий элемент (.prev())

можно так:

```
$('.btn-info').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())
})
```

Логика похожа. возвращаетесь до ближайшего tr  - идёте в низ до нужного (там можно класс поставить)

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял что требуется, то вот так

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
alert($(this).parent().prev().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This is</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info" class="btn btn-primary">Один </button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" class="btn btn-primary">Два</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```